# Can't Process Any String from a Txt file

Tags: regex, scala

This is definitely weird. I can't process a string from text file. The only thing I can do is to print it out.

Here is my code:

```
 val pattern = new Regex("</DOCUMENT>")   
    val file = Source.fromFile(fileLocale)(io.Codec("ISO8859-1"))
    for (line <- file.getLines()) {
//      line match {
//        case "</DOCUMENT>" => {println("found it!!!!!"); return} //break out
//        case _ => println(line)   //save lines to another file
//      }
      println(line.indexOf("PUBLIC"))
    }
```

First I was using regex and pattern match `pattern.findFirstIn()` and then match the result. Then I found I couldn't produce anything. I thought my regex was off because I don't know anything about regex (I'm trying to match a closing tag `</DOCUMENT>` in a txt file, as soon as I find the first closing tag, I exit out of the loop/function and save everything I read to a different file)

Please don't tell me to use JSoup. I'm dealing with a text file that is 23mb big and it already crushed my browser (written in C++) and my plain text editor.

I'm preprocessing the text file and reduce it to a much more desirable size, then I'll use JSoup to parse the HTML DOM tree.

However, since I can't use REGEX, I thought about plain string matching `case "</DOCUMENT>"`. Well, it did not work. THen I tried `line.indexOf("</DOCUMENT>")`. It wasn't working either. So I wonder if the problem is the `/` symbol, and I tried to find `PUBLIC`, which is definitely in the text file. Still, I can't find it. The results are all `-1`.

The only operation I can do, apparently, is to print out the line as is. What's going on!?

---

This is a test file I made from the original 23megabytes file:

> ```
> <SEC-DOCUMENT>0001000180-14-000019.txt : 20140221 <SEC-HEADER>0001000180-14-000019.hdr.sgml : 20140221
> ```
>
> 20140221171951 ACCESSION
>   NUMBER:       0001000180-14-000019 CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE: 10-K PUBLIC
>   DOCUMENT COUNT:       17 CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT:  20131229 FILED AS OF
>   DATE:     20140221 DATE AS OF CHANGE:     20140221
>
> ```
> FILER:
>
>   COMPANY DATA:           COMPANY CONFORMED NAME:         SANDISK CORP        CENTRAL INDEX KEY:          0001000180      STANDARD INDUSTRIAL CLASSIFICATION: COMPUTER
> ```
>
> STORAGE DEVICES [3572]        IRS NUMBER:             770191793       STATE OF
>   INCORPORATION:            DE      FISCAL YEAR END:            1229
>
> ```
>   FILING VALUES:      FORM TYPE:      10-K        SEC ACT:        1934 Act        SEC FILE NUMBER:    000-26734       FILM NUMBER:        14634715
>
>   BUSINESS ADDRESS:           STREET 1:       951 SANDISK DRIVE       CITY:           MILPITAS        STATE:          CA      ZIP:            95035       BUSINESS
> ```
>
> PHONE:        408-801-1000
>
> ```
>   MAIL ADDRESS:           STREET 1:       951 SANDISK DRIVE       CITY:           MILPITAS        STATE:          CA      ZIP:            95035 </SEC-HEADER> <DOCUMENT> <TYPE>10-K
> ```
>
> 1 sndk201310-k.htm FORM 10-K FY13
>                             SNDK 2013 10-K   
>     10-K 2 SECOND PART
>   FORM 10-K FY13
>
> ```
> </DOCUMENT> <DOCUMENT> <TYPE>10-K <SEQUENCE>2 <FILENAME>Third PART <DESCRIPTION>FORM 10-K FY13 <TEXT> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD
> ```
>
> HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the following:

```
val lines =  file.getLines.takeWhile( ! _.contains("</DOCUMENT>")
```

This will collect all the lines until the first one that contains `</DOCUMENT>` and returns an `Iterator[String]` which you can read once, or if you prefer a list:

```
val lines =  file.getLines.takeWhile( ! _.contains("</DOCUMENT>").toList
```

But if memory usage is a problem, you're better of using the `Iterator`, which reads the file on demand and doesn't need to allocate memory for all of it.

Comment: This is the solution I'm looking for, it is so simple and perfect and I love Scala. BUT!! This does not solve my problem. My problem is not to retrieve the piece elegantly. My problem is the program can't find `"</DOCUMENT>"`.

Comment: Like `line.find("</DOCUMENT>")` will return "null", assuming `find()` is a valid string function that will locate a piece of string.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'the program can't find </DOCUMENT>'. There is no `find` method in `String` to look for a string, you can use `contains` to find a `String` or `matches` with a regexp. Maybe your problem is empty space before/after `</DOCUMENT>`, try with `line.matches("""\s*<\DOCUMENT>\s*""")`

Comment: Yeah..I tried that option too. `val lines = line.contains("""\s*<\DOCUMENT>\s*""")` and every line I got is a `False`. You can actually see the original txt file up there. I attached a part of it.

Comment: I mean...this is really weird right? Do you have any idea what possibly might be going on? Maybe a codec problem?

Comment: if you're using `"""\s*<\DOCUMENT>\s*"""` you have to do it with the `matches` method, which takes a regexp as parameter. `contains` takes a literal `String`, which means it would actually look for the `\s*` symbols.

Comment: Yeah thank you for pointing that out. I used `matches`: ```val lines = line.matches("""\s*<\DOCUMENT>\s*""") if (lines) println(lines)``` but still, it prints out nothing.

Comment: It should be `if (lines) println(line)`

Comment: Yes I agree, but even if it is `print(lines)`, as long as the regex matches up with the string, it will print `true` right? It does not print anything, as if the regex did not match anything. So I'm just wondering what may be wrong...

Comment: There might be something wrong with the txt file...but thank you. I wrote a small matching program in Python and it didn't work either.